# How to get Excel Sheet into a Deedle data frame in F#

Tags: f#

I am trying to get data in excel into a Deedle data frame. I have used Excel provider to get the data but I am not sure how to get it into a record so that it can be taken into Deedle. My code that I have is shown below.

```
open Deedle
open FSharp.Interop.Excel

type TheFile = ExcelFile<"*******.xlsx","Sheet Desired">
let data = TheFile()
let data = data.Data
****figuring out how to convert to record****

let df = Frame.ofRecords data
```

I haven't figured out how to convert this data to a record in the special type sequence.

Comment: Maybe a map: `data |> Seq.map (fun r -> {| a = r.a ; b = r.b|}) |> Frame.ofRecords`

Comment: @AMieres, you are correct with his suggestion. Would you want to formulate a proper answer so you can get the credit for your solution? :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `map`, for instance:

```
data 
|> Seq.map (fun r -> {| a = r.a ; b = r.b |}) 
|> Frame.ofRecords
```

Comment: How would I do this if I didn't know what a and b are?

Comment: Why don't you know? Are you doing a generic application? Type providers are better for specific developments, in other words for a specific spreadsheet that you know the contents off.